# Proof that $(M,\cup)$ is a monoid but not a group

Tags: group-theory

$M$ is a set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. As an example could be $\{\{0\},\{1\},...\}$

I need to proof that $(M,\cup)$ forms a monoid but not a group.

I am not quite sure how I can proof that. But I have the following thoughts.

For $e = \emptyset$ there is $A \cup e = e \cup A =A$ for $A \in M$. So it forms a monoid.

It is not a group because there is no inverse for an union. But how do I proof that?

Comment: BTW, to prove that $M$ is a monoid you also have to prove that for all $A,B \in M$ we have $A\cup B \in M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that for every $A\in M$ there exists $B \in M$ such that $B\cup A =A \cup B=\emptyset$. Is it possible for $A\neq \emptyset$?..

Comment: it is not possible.

Comment: right. So basically you can prove it by producing a counter examples. Try to explain why if $A=\{1,2\}$ there is no $B\in M$ such that $A\cup B =\emptyset$.

Comment: that will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let us say for a non empty subset A there exists an inverse B.
Then $A \cup B = e$. But A $\subset$ A$\cup B $. This means A $\subset$ $e$. Clearly a contradiction.